# ng-style nested in ng-html-bind

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This isn't working for me, the style never gets applied but not sure if this would even be supported due to the nesting?

```
datas = [
  { 
   name:"item1", 
   svg:"<svg width="100" height="100"><circle ng-style="{fill:data.color}" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4"/</svg>"
  },
  { 
   name:"item2", 
   svg:"<svg width="200" height="60"><circle ng-style="{fill:data.color}" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4"/</svg>"
  }


]


   $scope.toTrusted = function(html_code) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
        }


<div ng-repeat="data in datas">

 <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>    
 <input type="text" ng-model="data.color">
 <div ng-bind-html="toTrusted(data.svg)"</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have to use ng-bind-html?

Comment: @Gerfried  I'm using ng-repeat on data in datas. I just think this way allows the view to look alot cleaner rather than having about 10 different ng-ifs filled with 10 massive inline svgs

Comment: Please show me how you would do it with ng-repeat. No need for ng-if, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Gerfried updated the example to use a ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
datas = [
  { 
   name:"item1", 
   color:"#ff0000",
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   strokeColor: "green"
  },
  { 
   name:"item2", 
   color:"#00ff00"
   width: 200,
   height: 60,
   strokeColor: "blue"
  }
]

<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>    
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.color">
    <svg width="{{data.width}}" height="{{data.height}}"><circle ng-style="{fill:data.color}" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="{{data.strokeColor}}" stroke-width="4"></svg>
</div>
```

As you see I have added more attributes to the data model. If you don't want to change your data, you can add the attributes later in your controller in a forEach loop with the propper conditions.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?